Getting "A client_id must be provided in the request" error in datadog synthetic multi test API
I am getting invlid client id error while trying to run one datadog multistep API for okta token generate API. the same collection is correctly working on postman but when i configured the same in datadog synthetic test, it failed for okta token generation API. i am stucked here.
Synthetic Test URL:  https://us5.datadoghq.com/synthetics/details/ar6-cia-g5w?from_ts=1727688079159&to_ts=1727691679159&live=true
Please refer below screenshots where in last image postman it's working with same set up.





